# BURN User Interface using External Theme

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I created a bootstraper, that checks the registry and UI components before installing the desired component.

I have an issue, I am using an External theme, I want to display BULK ( Alot of Data about the pre and post requites ) of my application. I need to display the information on the install page. Even a scroll bar would work i.e. Bulk data using   tags but a scroll-bar.

The important thing here is ( I am using an External Theme ) , So I have an XML for the interface.

Can you kindly give me an example, that how to display large information in Bootstraper Applications.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a custom Bootstrapper Application to represent your data. There isn't anything in wixstdba that would meet those sorts of requirements. You can write your custom BA in native or managed code and use all the UI widgets you want to display the UI how ever is best for your needs. You can see that the WiX toolset installer's UI is extremely custom (although it's more to show off that you can do something really different than for any practical purposes :).